# Java Netbeans , Metodos Para pilas

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Necesito si me pueden decir como seria un método para devolver la posición donde se encuentra el valor mínimo de los nodos ya que solo logre realizar el de la posición mayor y necesitaría un método para devolver el promedio de todos los números de los nodos si pueden ayudarme con estos métodos estaría muy agradecido la verdad les adjunto el código de mi clase

y les muestro el método de capturar la posición con el mayor dígito

```
public class PILA 
{
    class NODO
    {
        int Info;
        NODO sig;
    }  

    private NODO Raiz;

    public PILA() 
    {
        Raiz = null;
    }


     public int PosMayor()
    {
        NODO Reco = Raiz;

        if (Reco == null) 
        {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        else
        {
            int Contador = 1;
            int PosDelMayor = 1;
            int Mayor = Reco.Info;

            while(Reco != null)
            {
                if (Reco.Info > Mayor) 
                {
                    Mayor = Reco.Info;
                    PosDelMayor = Contador;
                }
                Reco = Reco.sig;
                Contador++;
            }    
            return PosDelMayor;
        }     
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes una idea errada sobre las pilas, cuando usamos pilas no se va pasando al siguiente dato sino que vamos sacando de nuestra pila ese dato y lo borramos, a lo mejor lo que quieres usar es una lista, que es otra estructura de datos
En todo caso aqui te dejo una solución posible pero es **imperante** que veas este vídeo para entender el funcionamiento de las pilas.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oduPQpqInl0&t=1017s

top()= devuelve el primer elemento de la pila pero no lo borra.
pop()= devuelve el primer elemento de la pila y lo borra.

```
public void posMenor(){
    Pila p= new Pila();
    int contador=1;
    int posMenor=1;
    int menor=999;
    while(p.top!=null){
    if((int)p.top()<menor){
    menor=(int)p.pop();
    posMenor=contador;
    }
    contador++;
    }
        System.out.println(posMenor + " " + menor);
    }


public A top() {
        if (esVacio()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return top.getElemento();
        }
    }

    public A pop() {
        if (esVacio()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            A elemento = top.getElemento();
            Nodo<A> aux = top.getSiguiente();
            top = null;
            top = aux;
            this.tamanio--;
            return elemento;

        }

    }
```